# How can this particular statement be made faster?

Tags: python, list

```
[[u'the', u'terse', u'announcement', u'state-run', u'news', u'agency', u'didnt', u'identify', u'the', u'aggressor', u'but', u'mister', u'has', u'accused', u'neighboring', u'country', u'of', u'threatening', u'to', u'attack', u'its', u'nuclear', u'installations'], [], [u'government', u'officials']]
```

I want to remove the empty lines, represented by empty brackets above[]. I am currently using:

```
with codecs.open("textfile.txt", "r", "utf-8") as f:
    for line in f:
        dataset.append(line.lower().strip().split()) #dataset contains the data above in the format shown
    lines=[sum((line for line in dataset if line), [])]
```

This statement takes pretty long to remove the empty lines. Is there a better way to remove empty lines from a list of lists and still maintain the format shown?

Comment: Why not just `lines = [line.lower().strip().split() for line in f if line.strip()]`?

Comment: Using `sum` for non-numeric addends is almost always a bad idea - it's usually quadratic time for operations that should be linear.

Comment: what is the `sum` call trying to accomplish? by the end of the program you end up with a list with only one element of a list of all the words in the file without any line separation.

Comment: if the end goal is to just get a list of all words that were separated by some kind of whitespace then you can just use `lines = [re.split("\W+",f.read())]` to get same result. (not sure why you put it inside `[ ]` to make a one element list)

Comment: sum is trying to remove empty new lines and combine all the lists into one list for further processing.

Answer (score 2):

You can skip the whitespace-only lines when reading the file:

```
with codecs.open("textfile.txt", "r", "utf-8") as f:
    dataset = [line.lower().split() for line in f if not line.isspace()]
```

Note that `split()` ignores leading/trailing whitespace, so `strip()` is redundant.

**EDIT**:

Your question is very unclear, but it seems from the comments that all you want to do is read a file and remove all the empty lines. If that is correct then you simply need to do:

```
with codecs.open("textfile.txt", "r", "utf-8") as f:
    dataset = [line.lower() for line in f if not line.isspace()]
```

Now `dataset` is a list of lower-cased lines (i.e. strings). If you want to combine them into one string, you can do:

```
text = ''.join(dataset)
```

Comment: Hi, but I want to combine sentences into one paragraph by removing the whitespaces. Applying this code, my file is treating them as 3 separate sentences.

Comment: @minks. See my updated answer. I'm still not completely sure what you want to do, but hopefully I've guessed right.

Answer (score 0):

I am a little confused why you are doing:

```
lines = [sum((line for line in dataset if line), [])]
```

First off by adding square brackets around the call to `sum` you end up with a list with one element: the result of `sum`, not sure if that was intended...

Regardless, the result of `sum()` will be a list of all the words in the file that were separated by whitespace, if this is the desired end result then you can simply use [`re.split`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.split):

```
with open(...) as f:
    links = [re.split("\W+",f.read())]
    #is it possible you instead wanted:
    #links = re.split("\W+",f.read())
```

the `"\W"` simply means any whitespace ("\n"," ","\t" etc.) and the `+` means (1 or more multiples) so it will handle multiple newlines or multiple spaces.